# /AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-25 11:50:16.455

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, android-intent

**My Code**

```
private static final LatLng AMSTERDAM = new LatLng(52.37518, 4.895439);
private static final LatLng PARIS = new LatLng(48.856132, 2.352448);
private static final LatLng FRANKFURT = new LatLng(50.111772, 8.682632);
private GoogleMap map;
private LatLngBounds latlngBounds;
private Button bNavigation;
private Polyline newPolyline;
private boolean isTravelingToParis = false;
private int width, height;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    getSreenDimanstions();

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    bNavigation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNavigation);
    bNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!isTravelingToParis)
            {
                isTravelingToParis = true;
                findDirections( AMSTERDAM.latitude, AMSTERDAM.longitude,PARIS.latitude, PARIS.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );
            }
            else
            {
                isTravelingToParis = false;
                findDirections( AMSTERDAM.latitude, AMSTERDAM.longitude, FRANKFURT.latitude, FRANKFURT.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );  
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, PARIS);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));

}

public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints) {
    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++) 
    {          
        rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
    }
    if (newPolyline != null)
    {
        newPolyline.remove();
    }
    newPolyline = map.addPolyline(rectLine);
    if (isTravelingToParis)
    {
        latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, PARIS);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));
    }
    else
    {
        latlngBounds = createLatLngBoundsObject(AMSTERDAM, FRANKFURT);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));
    }

}

private void getSreenDimanstions()
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth(); 
    height = display.getHeight(); 
}

private LatLngBounds createLatLngBoundsObject(LatLng firstLocation, LatLng secondLocation)
{
    if (firstLocation != null && secondLocation != null)
    {
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();    
        builder.include(firstLocation).include(secondLocation);

        return builder.build();
    }
    return null;
}

public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

    GetDirectionsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(this);
    asyncTask.execute(map); 
}
}
```

**MyLogCat**

```
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emildesign.navigationapplication/com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.emildesign.navigationapplication.NavigationActivity.onCreate(NavigationActivity.java:40)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    ... 11 more
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4857)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
03-25 11:50:16.455: E/AndroidRuntime(11838):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Do you have `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml, as specified in the last "Caused by" clause in the stack trace?

Comment: post your `Manifest` xml.

Answer (score 1):

In your posted `LogCat`, its clearly said that

```
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

May be you forgot to add the **Google Play services version** to your app's `Manifest`. Now add this declaration in your `Manifest` inside `<application>` element...

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In `onResume()` , you call:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latlngBounds, width, height, 150));
```

It may return null at times.

**2.** For

```
..:E/AndroidRuntime(11838): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:Binary XML file...
```

In `onCreate()`,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
```

And

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

The `fragment` with `id` `map` - should be in your `layout` `activity_navigation`--*case sensitive*.
The same should be declared as:

```
<fragment 
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
other layout properties />
```

**3.**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml
```

The meta tag in your `manifest` related to `googleplayservices` version, is declared incorrectly. The expected version is 4132500 but seems declared is 0.
Check:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Check the topic Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest @

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```